# Contactform not working as it should

Tags: php, html, ajax, post

I recently bought a template which has an included contact form with ajax and validation. I tried to apply my own script to it, but that won't work. It's probably something on the server side (my script). Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

This is the form on the contact page:

```
<form class="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact_form/contact_form.php">
                <div class="row">
                    <fieldset class="column column-1-2">
                        <input class="text-input" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Naam *">
                        <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email *">
                        <input class="text-input" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
                        <input class="text-input" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Onderwerp">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="column column-1-2">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Bericht *"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin-top-30">
                    <div class="column column-1-2">
                        <p>We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column column-1-2 align-right">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact_form" />
                        <div class="row margin-top-20 padding-bottom-20">
                            <a class="more submit-contact-form" href="#" title="SEND MESSAGE"><span>VERSTUUR</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is the ajax part:

```
//contact form
    if($(".contact-form").length)
    {
        $(".contact-form").each(function(){
            $(this)[0].reset();
        });
        $(".submit-contact-form").on("click", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#contact-form").submit();
        });
    }
    $(".contact-form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        var self = $(this);
        //if($(this).find(".total-cost").length)
        //  data.push({name: 'total-cost', value: $(this).find(".total-cost").val()});
        self.find(".block").block({
            message: false,
            overlayCSS: {
                opacity:'0.3',
                "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: self.attr("action"),
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json){
                self.find(".submit-contact-form, [name='submit'], [name='name'], [name='email'], [name='message']").qtip('destroy');
                if(typeof(json.isOk)!="undefined" && json.isOk)
                {
                    if(typeof(json.submit_message)!="undefined" && json.submit_message!="")
                    {
                        self.find(".submit-contact-form").qtip(
                        {
                            style: {
                                classes: 'ui-tooltip-success'
                            },
                            content: { 
                                text: json.submit_message 
                            },
                            position: { 
                                my: "right center",
                                at: "left center" 
                            }
                        }).qtip('show');
                        self[0].reset();
                        self.find(".cost-slider-input").trigger("change");
                        self.find(".cost-dropdown").selectmenu("refresh");
                        self.find("input[type='text'], textarea").trigger("focus").trigger("blur");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(typeof(json.submit_message)!="undefined" && json.submit_message!="")
                    {
                        self.find(".submit-contact-form").qtip(
                        {
                            style: {
                                classes: 'ui-tooltip-error'
                            },
                            content: { 
                                text: json.submit_message 
                            },
                            position: { 
                                my: "right center",
                                at: "left center" 
                            }
                        }).qtip('show');
                    }
                    if(typeof(json.error_name)!="undefined" && json.error_name!="")
                    {
                        self.find("[name='name']").qtip(
                        {
                            style: {
                                classes: 'ui-tooltip-error'
                            },
                            content: { 
                                text: json.error_name 
                            },
                            position: { 
                                my: "bottom center",
                                at: "top center" 
                            }
                        }).qtip('show');
                    }
                    if(typeof(json.error_email)!="undefined" && json.error_email!="")
                    {
                        self.find("[name='email']").qtip(
                        {
                            style: {
                                classes: 'ui-tooltip-error'
                            },
                            content: { 
                                text: json.error_email 
                            },
                            position: { 
                                my: "bottom center",
                                at: "top center" 
                            }
                        }).qtip('show');
                    }
                    if(typeof(json.error_message)!="undefined" && json.error_message!="")
                    {
                        self.find("[name='message']").qtip(
                        {
                            style: {
                                classes: 'ui-tooltip-error'
                            },
                            content: { 
                                text: json.error_message 
                            },
                            position: { 
                                my: "bottom center",
                                at: "top center" 
                            }
                        }).qtip('show');
                    }
                }
                self.find(".block").unblock();
            }
        });
    });
```

The mail script:

```
<?PHP
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$isValid = true;
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) 
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = 'Er is een contact aanvraag op website: '.$_POST['subject'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->addAddress("info@website.nl");     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);                      // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $texts = 'Er is een aanvraag op de website van website<br /> <br />
    <b>Naam:</b> '.$name.'<br />
    <b>E-mail adres:</b> '.$email.'<br />
    <b>Onderwerp:</b> '.$subject.'<br />
    <b>Vragen / Opmerkingen:</b> '.$message.'<br /><br /><br />
    ';

    $handtekening = '
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; font-size:10pt;line-height:22px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="160" valign="top" style="font-family:calibri;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;">
    [contents]
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160" valign="top" style="font-family:calibri;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;">
    <br><br>Met vriendelijke groet,<br><br>
    Helpdesk<br>
    <b>Website</b><br>
    <p></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table height="120" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; font-size:10pt;line-height:22px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="250" valign="top" style="font-family:calibri;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;border-top: 1px #000000 dotted; border-bottom: 1px #000000 dotted;">
    E:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="mailto:info@website.nl" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;">info@website.nl</a><br>
    T:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="tel:0181851859" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;">(0181) 851 859</a><br>
    W:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://website.nl" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;" target="_blank">www.website.nl</a><br>
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="font-family:calibri;padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;border-top: 1px #000000 dotted; border-bottom: 1px #000000 dotted;">
    <a href="http://website.nl/" target="_blank" title="Ga naar website">
    <img src="http://www.website.nl" alt="Ga naar website" style="font-family:calibri;text-align:right;margin:0px;padding:10px 0 10px 0;" border="0" width="232">
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:calibri;color:#a3a3a3;font-size:11px;margin-top:6px;line-height:14px;">
    <br>Dit e-mailbericht is uitsluitend bestemd voor de geadresseerde. Als dit bericht niet voor u bestemd is, wordt u vriendelijk verzocht dit aan de afzender te melden. website staat door de elektronische verzending van dit bericht niet in voor de juiste en volledige overbrenging van de inhoud, noch voor tijdige ontvangst daarvan. Voor informatie over website raadpleegt u <a href="http://website.nl" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;" target="_BLANK">website</a>.<br><br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

    $contents = preg_replace('/\[contents]/',$texts, $handtekening);
    $mail->msgHTML($contents);
    $mail->AltBody = $texts;
    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {
        $isValid = false;
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->From = 'info@website.nl';
    $mail->FromName = 'website';
    $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);           // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Bedankt voor uw aanvraag bij website';
    $texts = 'Geachte heer/mevrouw '.$naam.',<br /><br />
    Hartelijk dank voor uw aanvraag bij website<br />
    Wij reageren zo spoedig mogelijk op uw aanvraag.<br /><br />
    Uw gegevens worden nooit aan derden ter hand gesteld.
    ';
    $contents = preg_replace('/\[contents]/',$texts, $handtekening);
    $mail->msgHTML($contents);
    $mail->AltBody = $texts;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
    $isValid = false;
    }
    }else 
    {
        $isValid = false;
    }

    $array = array(
    'isValid' => $isValid
    );

    echo json_encode($array);
```

The script needs to send two mails. One to the sender as confirmation, and one for the receiver.

The validation is not working. I think the send script has some missing info.

Comment: I see != instead of !== in the javascript, not sure if that matters. In general you are not consequent in the usage of single and double quotes.
I would recommend to not access $_POST variables the way you do, it is better to filter them with filter_input() and also use filter_has_var() instead of isset(). See http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php.

Comment: The javascript is part of the template, and it works when I just keep their script. But that script is not what I want, since it only sends one email. And only sends to a hardcoded email adres, not the one you type in into the form.

Comment: Do you have more then one of these forms? You are setting a submit() on an ID inside a click function of a class. That is not logical.

Comment: I will take a look at it tonight, unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: @Lexib0y The submit button is a standard `a href` , with javascript it submits the form when clicking on the link, is that what you mean? I have only one form.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @MoshFeu No, nothing. So it's not finding the javascript. Because it doesn't show any error, not even: 'Message could not be send' which is what it's supposed to say when there is an error.

Comment: Is the browser arrive to this line `event.preventDefault();` at all?

Comment: @MoshFeu No it doesn't show that in the console log.

Comment: Try to add something like `console.log('test');` just after `$(".contact-form").submit(function(event){` and tell me if this message shown in the console.

Comment: @MoshFeu I added it, and it showed the test in the console log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95436/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-twan).

Answer (score 0):

you submit the form with ID contact-form

```
$("#contact-form").submit();
```

But handle the submit with

```
 $(".contact-form").submit(function(event){}
```

Try changing this to

```
 $("#contact-form").submit(function(event){}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work unfortunately. I don't think it is an issue on the JS side. But something in the send script. As if it doesn't find the validate/send script.

Comment: Can you see that in the server log?

Comment: Try to put the full url in the action field.

Comment: This is what it shows in the server log: https://i.gyazo.com/8a396d77cb0b0aeff10eef26859f9d98.png  I clicked it three times, so I think it does find the send script. Maybe the error is in something else. This is the server log on firefox: https://i.gyazo.com/bdf0a76332a5956eb8bdcc71d0fdc183.png

Comment: So, it's seems that the `ajax`s works. Please update your question.. `all ajax stops working` and I can't see where you are trying to validate.